# I have a list of Map like this List<Map<String, Object>>? rows how do i get seperate key and value and pass to a constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

rows = [
{
"name": "Ram",
"email": "ram@gmail.com",
"age": 23,
"DOB": "1990-12-01",
"indian": false
},
{
"name": "Shyam",
"email": "shyam23@gmail.com",
"age": 18,
"DOB": "1995-07-01",
"indian": true
},
]
and pass to
TableRow(
key: TabelCell(value:value))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
rows.map((e) => TableRow(key : '${e.name}')).toList();
```